# How to Dynamically create Form elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to dynamically create a form when user enter the number of row.

I tried the below code and spent over an hour searching on internet and can't solve that.

I was first of all doing it using PHP and I got stuck along the way, and people on the forum advised me to use Javascript.

I'm now confused !!  Please give me a clue !

```html
<p>
  <h3>Assignment 11]</h3>***********************</p>

<form action="" method="post">
  <b>Number of items</b> (between 1 and 30):
  <input type="number" name="numbItems" min="1" max="30" id="numbItem"> &nbsp&nbsp
  <input name="submit" value="Create" type="submit" id="createItem">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //document.getElementById("numbItem").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("createItem").onclick = function() {
    var price = document.getElementById("numbItem").value;
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  "your model price will be "  +  price ;
    alert(price + " items created.");
  };
</script>

<br>=============================================================================<br><br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspValue ( R )</td>
    <td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspTaxes ( R )</td>
    <td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspVAT ( % )</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>=============================================================================<br><br>

<?php if($numbItems=="1") { ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="item1" placeholder="E.g.: Gross Salary" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="value1" placeholder="E.g.: 12000" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="tax1" value="" readonly style="color:#f00;background:#ccc">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" name="vat1" min="0" max="100"> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input name="btnItem1" value="Calculate" type="button"><br><br>
  </form>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($numbItems=="2") { ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="item1" placeholder="E.g.: Gross Salary" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="value1" placeholder="E.g.: 12000" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="tax1" value="" readonly style="color:#f00;background:#ccc">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" name="vat1" min="0" max="100"> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input name="btnItem1" value="Calculate" type="submit"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="item2" placeholder="E.g.: Electricity" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="value2" placeholder="E.g.: 750" />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <input type="text" name="tax2" value="" readonly style="color:#f00;background:#ccc">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" name="vat2" min="0" max="100"> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input name="btnItem2" value="Calculate" type="submit"><br><br>
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you know Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: Why I'm asking because, if you want to make good user experience then you need to use Javascript else by using PHP you can do that but it'll not create a good ux.

Comment: Thanks user mi6crazyheart for your reply. I'm learning Javascript, so I can work on Javascript of course but jQuery I have no idea with that. What is it for by the way??

Comment: I've posted one sample code. Execute that & see how it's working. Maybe you require to modify it according to your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this following code. I've used Jquery to do this. If you've quite bit easy with javascript you can able to understand it. Hope, it'll help you to understand how u can handle such situation in Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );

        $( "#createItem" ).click(function() {
            var totalRows = $('#numbItem').val();

            var formHtml = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
            {
                formHtml += '&nbsp;<input type="text" name="item'+i+'"  placeholder="E.g.: Gross Salary" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="value'+i+'" placeholder="E.g.: 12000" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tax'+i+'" value="" readonly style="color:#f00;background:#ccc">&nbsp;<input type="number" name="vat'+i+'" min="0" max="100">&nbsp;<input name="btnItem'+i+'" value="Calculate" type="button"><br><br>';

            }

            $('#userForms').html(formHtml);
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <b>Number of items</b> (between 1 and 30):
    <input type="number" name="numbItem" min="1" max="30" id="numbItem"> &nbsp&nbsp
    <button id='createItem' type="button">Create</button>

    <div id=userForms></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks user mi6crazyheart. I wanted something like that. But I need to be able to do the following in every single row : When a user enter an amount in the second column, and set the VAT %, and click on "Calculate" button, the program must be able to do internal calculation [ amount * VAT / 100) and display the result in the 3rd column. Let assume : the user enters "800" in the 11th row, and set its VAT to 35, then the 3rd column of the 11th row will have "280" after the user click on "Calculate button". How can I modify your program and make it work like that !!! Thanks !!!

Comment: That's u can do on top of my sample code using javascript. I can also do that, but it'll not help u in long run. Better, u should know how to do that by yourself. So the trick - to read/write data from any point of HTML page u need one "id/class". So, u just require writing a program that read data from specific rows & makes some calculation on those data & displays the output on a specific position. My suggestion, take some time + learn some javascript+Jquery & build your own program. By the way, Sorry for replying in late.

Comment: I sort it out, thanks. So How do I display the Form after the html elements (Item, Value ( R ), Taxes ( R ), VAT ( % ) ) to appear like in my first post? I tried to move the Javascript code after the html code, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just use this(cut/paste) ```<div id=userForms></div>```(taken from my example) where ever u want to display those dynamic forms.

Answer (score 0):

if you have jQuery...
1.Add **id** element to the form or create a new **DIV** as follow

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="theForm"></div>
</form>
```

2.The jQuery function

```
$('#createItem').click(function(e){  
    $('#theForm').append('<< Your Items HTML Code >>')  
});
```

3.Change the **name** elements to  `item[]` instead of `item1` and the others

When you call `$_POST['item']` in PHP, the item will be read as an array. You can get all the items with a

```
$items = $_POST['item'];
foreach($items as $item){
    echo $item; //Output the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. Good luck

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $("#create").on("click",function(){
   var num = $("#num").val();
   if(num>1){
     for(i=1; i<=num; i++){
      $(".extra").append('<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
     }
   }else{
         $(".extra").append('<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
   }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="number" id="num">
  <button type="button" id="create">Create</button>
  <table>
   <tbody class="extra">
     
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out somethings, tag

```
    <hr>
```

is the html way to place separation you want.

When Using table, try to use thead,tbody and tfoot as it gives a straightforward way to add elemnts withoud touching headers or footers.

As for the main question, JQuery is powerfull but if you are a newbie, not knowing the basics will give you problems in the future. So as there are vere good JQuery answers here, here is a plain javascript solution

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <p>
      <h3>Assignment 11</h3>
      <hr>

      <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
          <b>Number of items</b> (between 1 and 30):
        </p>
        <input type="number" name="numbItems" min="1" max="30" step="1" id="numbItem">
        <br>
        <input name="submit" value="Create" type="button" id="createItem">
      </form>
      <hr>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Value ( R )</td>
            <td>Taxes ( R )</td>
            <td>VAT ( % )</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="itemsTableBody"></tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Value ( R )</td>
            <td>Taxes ( R )</td>
            <td>VAT ( % )</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("createItem").onclick = function() {
          var price = document.getElementById("numbItem").value;
          var tbody = document.getElementById("itemsTableBody");
          var olds = tbody.childNodes;
          for (; olds.length > 0;) {
            tbody.removeChild(olds[0]);
          }
          for (var i = 0; i < price; ++i) {
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            var td1 = document.createElement("td");
            var td2 = document.createElement("td");
            var td3 = document.createElement("td");
            var td4 = document.createElement("td");
            td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("td1 " + i));
            td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("td2 " + i));
            td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode("td3 " + i));
            td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode("td4 " + i));
            tr.appendChild(td1);
            tr.appendChild(td2);
            tr.appendChild(td3);
            tr.appendChild(td4);
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
          }
        };

      </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much HadesDX but you code appends on the existent !!! It should rather clear the old code and create new one.

Comment: @J.Doe so you want to clear the olds, and then create?

Comment: Many Thanks user user HadesDX. It works perfect !!! But I need to be able to do the following in every single row : When a user enter an amount in the second column, and set the VAT %, and click on "Calculate" button, the program must be able to do internal calculation [ amount * VAT / 100) and display the result in the 3rd column. Let assume : the user enters "800" in the 11th row, and set its VAT to 35, then the 3rd column of the 11th row will have "280" after the user click on "Calculate button". How can I modify your program and make it work like that !!! Thanks !!!

Comment: Sorry not to respond early as I'm using Internet Cafe, so here having Internet at home is still a LUXURY !!! I can't afford it !!